# Remove user from Jenkins via groovy script when role based strategy is used

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-cli

I am trying to automate Jenkins user deletion. Groovy script which I tried is as below.

`import hudson.model.User
User u = User.get('rh54')
u.delete()`

Mentioned groovy script does not delete when user is LDAP integrated. Also Security realm which is being used is Role-based Strategy.

Please suggest

Comment: I tested the same script for Role-Based strategy and it deleted the user successfully. Could you please let us know how you are executing the groovy script? Also, please post the contents of your script here.

Comment: Below is the script which I am using to delete the user from `Jenkins.import hudson.model.User
User u = User.get(id)
u.delete()`

Comment: Also I am running the script from Script Console. Id has been given the value in the script with which the user is created. Also user is not maintained in Jenkins internal database. User is authenticated against the LDAP.

Comment: I think this groovy script can just delete users within `Jenkins’ own user database` security realm. Are you sure it works fine with **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy** in `LDAP` realm?

Comment: Groovy script is only able to get the user using the id but it is not able to delete the user when **Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy** is used(In LDAP realm). Apologies for stating that it works fine with the above strategy in the previous comments.

Comment: Looks like you need a groovy script that deletes users from `LDAP`. In that case, you need to fetch LDAP server information from `Jenkin's LDAP plugin`, connect to it from groovy and perform the deletion.

Comment: When the user leaves the organization, he/she will be removed from LDAP server. But the entry still exists in Jenkins. I would like to remove the  user from Jenkins and not from the LDAP server. Please suggest.

Comment: Found that removing all the permissions of a user will eventually remove the user from Jenkins. Please help me in removing all the permissions of user in **Role-Based strategy** in **Groovy script**

Comment: Do you need script to remove all roles associated with a given user?

Comment: Yes. Need a script which will uncheck the roles associated with a particular user. Ideally that user should not to be mapped to any roles.

Comment: Please see if the script in my answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The below groovy script should create a new instance of `RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy` excluding the given user from all roles.

**Please note that I've not tested it thoroughly and make sure to take a backup of your Jenkins instance before testing this script.**

```
import hudson.model.*
import com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.*

String removeRolesFromUser="test"

def roleBasedAuthorizationStrategy = Jenkins.getInstance().getAuthorizationStrategy()

if(roleBasedAuthorizationStrategy instanceof RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy){
    boolean changed=false
    Map<String, RoleMap> roleMaps = roleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.getRoleMaps()
    RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy updatedRoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy = new RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy()
    for(Map.Entry<String, RoleMap> roleMapEntry : roleMaps.entrySet()){
        Set<Role> roleSet = roleMapEntry.getValue().getRoles()
        for(Role role : roleSet){
            updatedRoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.addRole(roleMapEntry.getKey(),role);
            for(String addUserAgain : roleMapEntry.getValue().getSidsForRole(role.getName())){
              if(!addUserAgain.equals(removeRolesFromUser)){
                updatedRoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy.assignRole(roleMapEntry.getKey(),role,addUserAgain)
              }else{
                println("User : " + removeRolesFromUser + " excluded from role : " + role.getName())
                changed=true
              }
            }
        }
    }
    if(changed){
        Jenkins.getInstance().setAuthorizationStrategy(updatedRoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy)
        println("INFO: Authorization strategy updated, user " + removeRolesFromUser + " removed from all roles.")
        Jenkins.getInstance().save();
        println("INFO: Authorization strategy saved to disk.")
    }else{
        println("INFO: No changes made to Authorization strategy since user : " + removeRolesFromUser + " does not belong to any role!")
    }
}else{
    println("ERROR : This script works only for RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy!")
}
```